# VB.net: CInt returning -1 on a (seemingly valid) string

Tags: vb.net

I have a strange problem where CInt (as well as Convert.ToInt32 or even Val) return -1 for a string "500". Using [Gurock's SmartInspect](http://www.gurock.com/products/smartinspect/) for logging, I've checked all values at runtime (SiAuto... logs something, I'm posting the log below the code). Would appreciate some hlp :)

Thanks

Michael

```
Si.Auto.Main.LogString("QueryString.q1",GetQueryStringParam("q1","0"))
' is it really "500" as it seems?
SiAuto.Main.LogBool("Is q1 = 500 in query-string?","500"=GetQueryStringParam("q1","0"))
q1 = CInt(GetQueryStringParam("q1","0"))
'don't worry abt that q1a-bit, the first string is just the title...
SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1a",q1)

q1 = Convert.ToInt32(GetQueryStringParam("q1","0"))
SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1b",q1)

q1 = val(GetQueryStringParam("q1","0"))
SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1c",q1)
```

And here's the log:

```
QueryString.q1 = "500"
Is q1 = 500 in query-string? = True
q1a = -1
q1b = -1
q1c = -1
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, tried that, still no joy :(

q1s = GetQueryStringParam("q1","0")
SiAuto.Main.LogString("QueryString.q1",q1s)
 
SiAuto.Main.LogBool("Is q1 = 500 in query-string?","500"=q1s)
q1 = CInt(q1s)

SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1a",q1)
 
q1 = Convert.ToInt32(q1s)
SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1b",q1)
 
q1 = val(q1s)
SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1c",q1)

q1 = Integer.Parse(q1s)
SiAuto.Main.LogInt("q1d",q1)

Only -1 in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, too bad, sorry guys, I found the fault: *someone* had declared q1 as Boolean :(

Comment: `Option Strict On` - do it now!

Answer (score 4):

Rather than making repeated calls to `GetQueryStringParam()` (what are you using, by the way?), store this value in a local `string` variable. This will make both your code and testing more reliable by eliminating the possibility that your function is behaving in a nondeterministic manner.

In any event, look into `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` for your conversions as well, though what you have appears that it SHOULD work.

**Edit**

If none of that works, my only suggestion would be--and yes, this may actually do something--running the code under another account on your computer, or on another computer altogether. If your windows profile is corrupted you can have issues converting formattable data types to a from a string.

Comment: Oops, sorry, posted my comment above - #Fail :(
Anyway, tried that, did not help.
GetQueryStringParam is just a thin cover for Request.GetQueryString to handle default-vals for optional qs-params more easily.

Comment: Adam, I tried to un under another account and have also taken the program to my Win2003-server - same mis-behaviour everywhere :((